# match / find rows based on multiple required values in a single row in R

Tags: r, dataframe

This must be a duplicate but I can't find it. So here goes.

I have a data.frame with two columns. One contains a group and the other contains a criterion. A group can contain many different criteria, but only one per row. I want to identify groups that contain three specific criteria (but that will appear on different rows. In my case, I want to identify all groups that contains the criteria "I","E","C". Groups may contain any number and combination of these and several other letters.

```
test <- data.frame(grp=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4),val=c("C","I","E","I","C","E","I","A","C","I","E","E","A"))

> test
  grp val
1    1   C
2    1   I
3    2   E
4    2   I
5    2   C
6    3   E
7    3   I
8    3   A
9    4   C
10   4   I
11   4   E
12   4   E
13   4   A
```

In the above example, I want to identify grp 2, and 4 because each of these contains the letters E, I, and C.

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose the three innermost unique() calls are pretty redundant and unnecessary. My actual dataset is several million rows and I wasn't sure if it would be faster that way.

Comment: Interesting problem! It is known as **and/or query dilemma** in the SQL database context because the **and** constraint requires constraining over more than one row (which is not SQLs strength). I am eager to see a (better) R solution!

Comment: How many unique `val` are in your dataset? Depending on the number, that information may guide some of the solutions.

Comment: do you expect a solution that searches for three letters or is the number of letters (that are combined via **logical and**) to be flexible too?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns There are 6 different unique val.

Comment: @RYoda I'm not worried at all about how many times each letter or combination of letters shows up, as long as all three letters show up at least once. Does that answer your question?

Comment: How come `grp` 3 is identified? It doesn't contain `C`?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns You are totally right. I was actually just playing with my example and discovered the same thing. I have edited the question to remove my supposedly correct (ie., totally incorrect) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution. `%in%` is vectorized so `c("E", "I", "C") %in% val` returns a logical vector of length three. For the target groups, passing that vector to `all()` returns `TRUE`. That's our filter, and we run it within each group using `group_by()`.

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>%
  filter(all(c("E", "I", "C") %in% val))
# Source: local data frame [8 x 2]
# Groups: grp [2]
# 
#     grp    val
#   (dbl) (fctr)
# 1     2      E
# 2     2      I
# 3     2      C
# 4     4      C
# 5     4      I
# 6     4      E
# 7     4      E
# 8     4      A
```

Or if this output would be handier (thanks @Frank),

```
test %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarise(matching = all(c("E", "I", "C") %in% val))
# Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
# 
#     grp matching
#   (dbl)    (lgl)
# 1     1    FALSE
# 2     2     TRUE
# 3     3    FALSE
# 4     4     TRUE
```

Comment: Here's a similar option in base: `tapply(test$val, test$grp, function(x) all(myvals %in% x))` where `myvals = c("E","I","C")`. I think `summarise` is a better fit that `filter` here if the OP just wants to know which groups pass the criterion.

Comment: Didn't know about all(). Great addition from both of you.

Comment: Good thought. Wasn't sure whether OP really wanted the groups or the rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)

test <- data.frame(grp=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4),val=c("C","I","E","I","C","E","I","A","C","I","E","E","A"))

setDT(test)      # convert the data.frame into a data.table
group.counts <- dcast(test, grp ~ val)  # count number of same values per group and create one column per val with the count in the cell
group.counts[I>0 & E>0 & C>0,]          # now filtering is easy
```

Results in:

```
   grp A C E I
1:   2 0 1 1 1
2:   4 1 1 2 1
```

Instead of returning the group numbers only you could also "join" the resulting group numbers with the original data to show the "raw" data rows of each group that matches:

```
test[group.counts[I>0 & E>0 & C>0,], .SD, on="grp" ]
```

This shows:

```
   grp val
1:   2   E
2:   2   I
3:   2   C
4:   4   C
5:   4   I
6:   4   E
7:   4   E
8:   4   A
```

PS: Just to understand the solution easier: The counts for all groups are:

```
> group.counts
   grp A C E I
1:   1 0 1 0 1
2:   2 0 1 1 1
3:   3 1 0 1 1
4:   4 1 1 2 1
```