# return only the count of rows that match multiple criteria at once in r

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I am referencing the already answered question that has gotten me as close as possible: [match / find rows based on multiple required values in a single row in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923311/match-find-rows-based-on-multiple-required-values-in-a-single-row-in-r)

Sample dataframe:

```
test <- data.frame(grp=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4),val=c("C","I","E","I","C","E","I","A","C","I","E","E","A"))
```

I modified an answer to return only the grp values that match all criteria.

```
library('dplyr')
test %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarise(matching = all(c("A", "I", "C") %in% val)) %>% filter(matching ==TRUE)
```

From here, I need to just return the number of grps that match the criteria, as a single numerical value that can be pasted into a single cell of a separate dataframe. I am trying to find matches for multiple different sets of criteria over the same data.frame. (ex. the number of groups that match the criteria A I and C; the number of groups that match the criteria E, A and I; the number of groups that match the criteria A, I and E; (etc.))

In the example, it returns a tibble:

```
A tibble: 1 x 2
    grp matching
  <dbl> <lgl>   
1     4 TRUE
```

So there is one "grp" that matches the determined critera. I need to return that number: 1.

if my criteria is only the letter I, then I would want the code to return the number **4**, as all groups (1, 2, 3, and 4) match to the letter I.

If my criteria is the letter A, then I would want the code to return the number **2**, since only groups 3 and 4 match to the letter A

Comment: There is no `species` column.  Do you need `test %>% group_by(grp) %>% filter(all(c("A", "I", "C") %in% val)) %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise(out = toString(sort(unique(val))))`

Comment: sorry! species is from my own dataframe, I just edited it back to grp

Comment: I am not sure whatt is the expected output.  Posted a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are looking for different `combn`inations of 'val' to `filter`, use `combn` to returns combinations of the 'val' taken `m = 3` at a time, grouped by 'grp', `filter` the rows of 'test' where `all` of the combinations are present in 'val', `summarise` by `paste`ing the `sort`ed `unique` values of 'val' and bind the `list` to a single data.frame with `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
combn(levels(test$val), 3, simplify = FALSE,
     FUN = function(x)
      test %>%
         group_by(grp) %>%
         filter(all(x  %in% val)) %>% 
         summarise(out = toString(sort(unique(val))))) %>% 
  bind_rows
```

#### Update

If we just want to get a single row as TRUE, after `filter`ing the 'grp' based on the condition, `summarise` by creating the `matching` as TRUE

```
test %>%
     group_by(grp) %>%
     filter(all(c("A", "I", "C") %in% val)) %>%
     summarise(matching = TRUE)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#    grp matching
#  <dbl> <lgl>   
#1     4 TRUE
```

Or switch the `summarise` and `filter` steps

```
test %>% 
   group_by(grp) %>% 
   summarise(matching = all(c("A", "I", "C") %in% val)) %>% 
   filter(matching)  %>%
   pull(matching) %>%
   sum 
#[1] 1
```

---

Or can be made more compact

```
test %>% 
    group_by(grp) %>%
    summarise(matching = all(c("A", "I", "C") %in% val)) %>% 
    pull(matching) %>% 
    sum
 #[1] 1
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
sum(!rowSums(table(test) == 0))
#[1] 1
```

Comment: I edited the question to include the expected output. from my example, I just want to get a single number: 1. would like to modify the existing code so that it returns the number of groups (where "grp" column corresponds to the group name) that match my criteria

Comment: from there, how do I get it to return just the number 1- rather than a tibble?

Comment: @dplyd You can convert to `data.frame` with `%>% as.data.frame` at the end (if that is what you meant).  Or if you are interested only in the `grp` column `%>% pull(grp)`

Comment: I'm interested only in the matching column. I want the count of matching= TRUE, and in the example, that count would be 1 :)

Comment: but the return value must just be the number- it can't be inside of a tibble or data.frame, or anything.

Comment: I may be confused, but the answer still returns a tibble

Comment: a<- test %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  filter(all(c("A", "I", "C") %in% val)) %>%
  summarise(matching = TRUE)
nrow(a)                                                                                                                        this gets the right answer, but can I get it without creating a dataframe "a" at all?

Comment: @dplyd I already showed the value `1` in two of my answers.  Not sure what you really wanted

Answer (score 0):

First you filter the with your criteria, then you check which group is in all the letters you want. Maybe is not the best way to do it, but it works

```
criteria = c('A','I','C')
return = subset(test,test$val %in% criteria)
count = 0

for(group in unique(return$grp))
{
  criteriaSum =  sum(criteria %in% unique(return$val[return$grp == group]))
  if(criteriaSum == length(criteria))
    count = count + 1
}
```

Comment: this returns the number of rows that match any of the letters, not the number of groups that match all criteria. Any ideas? I edited my original question for more clarity.

Comment: Edited the post with the answer

Comment: Error in unique(return$val[return$grp == group]) : 
  object 'group' not found

Comment: 'group' is the object in the for, how was it not found? I tested this code for all the cases in your question and it worked.