# Trying to use R to search for families in a data set

Tags: r

I have a data set similar to this tibble:

```
test_families <- tribble(
  ~PatientID, ~RelatedPatientID, ~RelationshipTypeCd,
  #--|---|---
 101, 101, "PT",
 101, 202, "Sibling",
 101, 203, "Sibling",
 101, 204, "Sibling",
 101, 205, "Daughter",
 101, 206, "Son",
 101, 207, "Wife",
 201, 201, "PT",
 201, 302, "Son"
)
```

I am trying to write code that will find families of the type Mother-Father-Child-Child. I have figured out how to restrict my data to families of at least 4 members using this code:

```
test_families4plus <- test_families %>%
   group_by(PatientID) %>%
   filter(n() >=4)
```

I then tried to use the `group_by` function to search for families, but I can't get it to work. Code like this does not return any results:

```
test_families4plus %>%
   group_by(PatientID) %>%
   filter(RelationshipTypeCd == "PT" & 
              RelationshipTypeCd == "Son"
              )
```

I assume this is because there is not a single row that contains both "PT" and "Son." Apparently, don't really understand how `group_by` works.

How else can I `filter` families by looking at rows that all have the same value at PatientID?

Comment: Could you show me your desired output please?

Comment: I'm trying to find families with the following members: Mother, Father, Child, Child. One way this would look in my data is (PT, Wife, Daugther, Son). My desired output, if filtering test_families, would be the rows with 101 in the PatientID column, and 101, 205, 206, and 207, in the RelatedPatientID column, because it satisfies (PT, Wife, Daugther, Son), while the 201 family does not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the additional comment you made, I got a clearer picture of what you were trying to do. Here's a solution that involves some data wrangling (see comments for each step) and a final join to recover the original "RelatedPatientID".

```
library(tidyverse)

# Get families that have PT, Wife and at least 2 Children
df1 <- test_families %>%
  # Group by patient id and relationship
  group_by(PatientID,RelationshipTypeCd) %>%
  # count
  count() %>%
  # Change data to wide format
  pivot_wider(id_cols = PatientID,
              names_from = "RelationshipTypeCd",
              values_from = "n") %>%
  # Add a column that sums daughter and son as Child
  mutate(Child = Daughter + Son) %>%
  # Filter patient id that has at least one count for PT and Wife, and at least two Child
  filter(PT >= 1 & Wife >= 1 & Child >= 2) %>%
  # Change data to long format
  pivot_longer(cols = -PatientID,
               names_to = "RelationshipTypeCd") %>%
  # Stay only with rows with PT, Wife, Son, Daughter entries
  filter(RelationshipTypeCd %in% c("Daughter","PT","Son","Wife"))

# Join the previous df with the original df to get the RelatedPatientID
df1 %>%
  left_join(test_families, by = c("PatientID", "RelationshipTypeCd"))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   PatientID [1]
#  PatientID RelationshipTypeCd value RelatedPatientID
#      <dbl> <chr>              <int>            <dbl>
#1       101 Daughter               1              205
#2       101 PT                     1              101
#3       101 Son                    1              206
#4       101 Wife                   1              207
```

Comment: Using `|` doesn't work, because it returns any family that has, for example, just a son, but not a son and a daughter and a wife.

Comment: I tried using the `%in%` operator, and had similar issues. It returns families that have any value in the vector I use `%in%` to compare to, and doesn't select for only those families that satisfy ALL of the values in the vector.

Comment: I edited the answer based on the information you provided in your last comment.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. As I said in my answer, it led me to find a solution. I also really like your idea of mutating my list to change family members to be simpler (both daughter and son are equivalent as child). This will make searching my real data set much easier. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's answers. Using your suggestions, I found a really elegant solution here: [match / find rows based on multiple required values in a single row in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923311/match-find-rows-based-on-multiple-required-values-in-a-single-row-in-r)

Here is the code for my data:

```
library(dplyr)
(test_families %>%
   group_by(PatientID) %>%
   filter(all(c("PT","Daughter", "Son", "Wife") %in% RelationshipTypeCd))
              )
```

This preserves the entire family, even if members (e.g. "Sibling") wasn't part of the search strategy.